# Clear MatPlotLib figure in Jupyter Python notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want a 3D scatter plot in MatPlotLib to be rotated interactively in a Jupyter Python notebook. For that reason I integrated a slider from `ipywidgets` to update the view angle. The test code below shows what I am trying to achieve. The problem is that a new figure is added below the previous one, instead of the current figure cleared. I tried `plt.close(fig)`, `plt.cla()` and `plt.clf()` without success. (further I realize that there is overhead in recreating the figure and axes but that is the lesser part of my current concerns...)

Here is the (test) code:

```
# init
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

# generate test data
x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
z = np.random.rand(100)

# prepare plot
def draw_plot(angle1 = 20, angle2 = 40):
    # create figure
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
    ax.scatter(x, y, z)

    # set view angle
    ax.view_init(angle1, angle2)

    # show plot
    plt.show()

# prepare widgets
angle1_slider = widgets.IntSlider(20, min = 0, max = 60)
angle1_label = widgets.Label(value = 'Angle 1 value is: ' + str(angle1_slider.value))
display(angle1_slider, angle1_label)

# handle angle 1 update
def update_angle1(value):
    draw_plot(angle1 = value['new'])
    angle1_label.value = 'Angle 1 value is: ' + str(value.new)

angle1_slider.observe(update_angle1, names = 'value')

# draw initial plot
draw_plot()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you call overhead is the source of the problem. Or in other words: If in each call to the function, a new figure is created, is it surprising that you will end up with a lot of figures?

The idea is of course to draw a single figure. In order to be able to later update the figure the `%matplotlib notebook` backend is needed.

The function that gets called when changing the slider will then only need to update the viewing angle and redraw the canvas.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
%matplotlib notebook

# generate test data
x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
z = np.random.rand(100)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
ax.view_init(20, 40)
# show plot
plt.show()

def update_plot(angle1 = 20, angle2 = 40):
    # set view angle
    ax.view_init(angle1, angle2)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

# prepare widgets
angle1_slider = widgets.IntSlider(20, min = 0, max = 60)
angle1_label = widgets.Label(value = 'Angle 1 value is: ' + str(angle1_slider.value))
display(angle1_slider, angle1_label)

# handle angle 1 update
def update_angle1(value):
    update_plot(angle1 = value['new'])
    angle1_label.value = 'Angle 1 value is: ' + str(value.new)

angle1_slider.observe(update_angle1, names = 'value')
```

This is how it would look like:

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I did not know `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` which solved the issue indeed. And even better, I always used `%matplotlib inline` but `%matplotlib notebook` is very useful too! Thanks!